# How to specify directory path during migrations run

Tags: php, database-migration, phinx

How can I specify the directory to use for migrations while running the migrations with phinx, I am looking for something like

```
vendor/bin/phinx migrate --path = path/to/directory
```

Comment: I have never heard of Phinx but [the documentation shows how to specify migration paths](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/configuration.html#migration-paths) in a config file.  Does that help?

Comment: no I want to specify path while running the migrations

Comment: That's what the config file does.  I guess you mean on the command line? You might want to update your question to clarify.